# Max retry count not working in RetryExponential class

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-service-fabric, servicebus

```
SubscriptionClient receiver = messageFactory.CreateSubscriptionClient("NewTopic", subscriberId);
        TimeSpan e = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0, 0);
        RetryExponential x = new RetryExponential(e,e,e,e,2);
            OnMessageOptions options = new OnMessageOptions();
            options.AutoComplete = false; 
            //options.AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            options.ExceptionReceived += options_ExceptionReceived;
            receiver.OnMessage(receivedMessage =>
            {
                try
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(receivedMessage.Label);

                    bool t = receivedMessage.IsBodyConsumed;
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message received: {0}", receivedMessage.GetBody<string>()));
                    Console.WriteLine(receivedMessage.SequenceNumber);
                    Console.WriteLine(receivedMessage.TimeToLive);
                    Console.WriteLine(receivedMessage.To);

                    Console.WriteLine(receivedMessage.DeliveryCount);



                    receivedMessage.Abandon();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // Indicates a problem, unlock message in subscription.
                    receivedMessage.Abandon();
                }
            }, options);
```

Hi All,
In the retryExponential Constructor i set the maxRetryCount as 2.
And i delibretly Abandon the message in Onmessage to check the max retry count. Even after setting the retry count to 2 i am receiving the message more than 2 times.
--TIA

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're confusing [transient fault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-retry-service-specific/#service-bus-retry-guidelines) handling with [dead lettering.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dead-letter-queues/)

The retry mechanism you're using is to cope with distributed computing issues. Like throttling and service unavailability.

If you're unable to handle an incoming message, you usually move it to the DLQ after some attempts.

(and you're not using the 'x' variable)

Comment: aha missed this piece of code receiver.RetryPolicy = x;  I am assigning retry policy to receiver. this will control the maxretry attempts now?

Comment: SubscriptionClient receiver = messageFactory.CreateSubscriptionClient("NewTopic", subscriberId);  receiver.RetryPolicy =
new RetryExponential(
   minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
   maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
     deltaBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), terminationTimeBuffer: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
   maxRetryCount: 3); Even though it's retrying for 10 times.  for retrying  i Abandoned  the message

Comment: please read this too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.maxdeliverycount.aspx

Comment: I am using topic subscriptions . I didn't see any where i can set MaxDeliveryCount property.